# remove permanant rendring warning in android studio

Tags: android, rendering

how can i avoid or remove rendering problem warning permanently
i am using **Android Studio 2.2.3**.

i m getting rendering problems in most of my XML files
and my layout files not show any of my controls or design 
guys help me to solve this problem
and if possible , try to tell me how can i permanently block these warning.

this is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "design.ray.com.finalproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    // compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    //compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress the warnings on Android Studio.

`Analyze > Inspect Code` find the warning the you want to suppress and click it then `Alt+Enter` find suppress warning on the menu.